# Powershell Relative path with foreach

Tags: windows, powershell, file-access

Can someone explain me, how to have a relative path in the foreach? 
I want to execute the statements on every found file.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Entw\test*.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $dt=[System.IO.File]::GetCreationTime("C:\test\test.txt")
    $dt2=New-TimeSpan -Minutes 60
    $dt=$dt-$dt2
    [System.IO.File]::SetCreationTime("C:\test\test.txt", $dt)
    [System.IO.File]::SetLastWriteTime("C:\test\test.txt", $dt)
}
```

test.txt should be relative, even the path.

Comment: Use `$_.FullName`

Answer (score 1):

add relative path and executes the statement (in my case changing meta data of file) for every found file

```
$directorypath=get-location
echo $directorypath

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $directorypath\*.txt){
        #do something
}
```